# Help needed for the given question

Tags: number-theory

Given that m,n are natural numbers, when can $3^m + 3^n +1$ be a perfect square?

This question was asked in today's exam. I am stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you tell us some steps you did? where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: Hint: perhaps $\mod 4$ can help.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality assume $m>n$ and let the perfect square be $(a+1)^2$. Then $$a(a+2)=3^n(3^{m-n}+1)$$ You can now look at the possibilities for the factor of $3^n$.